# PowerPoint decreased performance

Tags: performance, vsto, powerpoint

We're having an odd issue with PowerPoint: we have a .NET-based add-in that programmatically inserts a set of shapes in the current slide. The very first time the set of shapes is generated, the total operation requires under one second.
If the user repeats the operation, the duration increases again and again, until it can reach fifteen seconds, probably more (we've stopped testing at that value).
If we restart PowerPoint, the operation needs again less then a second to complete.
We've tried to call GC.Collect at certain points in time and we're considering fully rewriting the shapes set generation code to generate all shapes in a certain sequence, however this is a very costly option.
Do you have other suggestions on how to diagnose this issue or how to fix it?

A simple code sequence that reproduces this issue follows.

```
// Attach the callback below to a button in your add-in ribbon.
public void OnDevBtnReproduceRenderingPerformanceIssue(IRibbonControl control)
{
     // Generate a decent set of shapes on the current slide,
     // delete them, repeat until rendering time exceeds a certain value.
     var slide = (Slide)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide;
     var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

     for (var iter = 0; iter < 1000; iter++)
     {
         stopwatch.Start();
         GenerateShapesSet(slide);
         DeleteAllShapes(slide);
         stopwatch.Stop();
         Debug.Print("Render+delete took {0} ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
         stopwatch.Reset();
      }
 }

 private static void DeleteAllShapes(Slide slide)
 {
      while (slide.Shapes.Count > 0)
      {
         slide.Shapes[1].Delete();
      }
 }

 private static void GenerateShapesSet(Slide slide )
 {
     var shapesCount = 100;

      for (var iter = 0; iter < shapesCount; iter ++)
      {
          var shape = slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(
                MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal,
                100,
                100,
                100,
                100
                );
          shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Test test test";
          shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "+mn-lt";
      }
 }
```

We've tried releasing all COM references to shapes, however this didn't fix the issue.
When the code executes, one can see the rendering+delete time increasing from 200 ms to 10 seconds.

Comment: any help without seeing the code would be difficult.

Comment: @KazJaw: I'll have to write a code sequence to reproduce the issue and then I'll publish on my SkyDrive. I'm not allowed to post the actual code and it's a few thousands lines of code, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution: after each shapes delete/create batch, call StartNewUndoEntry.
With this call, the rendering time no longer increases with each batch.